# Generating UML from C++ code?

Tags: c++, uml

Is there a tool that can parse C++ files within a project and generate UML from it?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Here are a few options:

Step-by-Step Guide to Reverse Engineering Code into UML Diagrams with Microsoft Visio 2000 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140255(office.10).aspx

BoUML - https://www.bouml.fr/features.html

StarUML - https://staruml.io/

Reverse engineering of the UML class diagram from C++ code in presence of weakly typed containers (2001) - http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.27.9064

Umbrello UML Modeller - https://apps.kde.org/umbrello/

A list of other tools to look at - [http://plg.uwaterloo.ca/~migod/uml.html](http://plg.uwaterloo.ca/%7Emigod/uml.html)

Comment: Reaccepted to the more thorough answer.

Comment: Umbrello seems to be for Linux/KDE only.

Comment: See similar questions [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203015/automatically-generate-a-uml-diagram-of-my-c-code) and [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407948/c-to-uml-reverse-engineer-round-trip-engineering) and [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577489/c-uml-class-diagram-autogeneration).

Comment: BoUML is not free!

Comment: StarUML does the job

Comment: StarUML failed super hard to produce anything helpful whatsoever.

Comment: BoUML is free again!

Comment: BoUML is not the greatest tool. Very dated UI and struggles hard with new C++ syntax or dependencies it doesn't know.

Comment: BoUML is now free again!!!

Comment: Modelio does the job

Comment: umbrello didn't create and gave error opening a file as if it didn't have permission whilethe file had world wide permissions.

Comment: As far as I can find, umbrello does not generate UML diagrams.

Comment: @dannymo StarUML doesn't do the job. It only imports classes, which was also broken in my case. It doesn't create class diagrams(dependencies between classes).

Answer (score 56):

If its just diagrams that you want, [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org) does a pretty good job.

Comment: I just got complete class hierarchy on a +300K LOC project with Doxygen, it really does a pretty well job!

Comment: Not exactly. For example: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/diagrams.html . Doesn't generate the dependencies of the class, only what classes it inherited from. On the page to the example, there is class B that depends on class A but the output image doesn't show it, it only shows inheritance.

Answer (score 16):

I've developed a tool called [Doxygraph](http://code.google.com/p/doxygraph/) which can parse the XML generated by Doxygen and turn it into an interactive UML class diagram which you can view in a web browser or import into any software that can read Graphviz "dot" files.

Comment: Very nice application! Apart from the fact that it depends on quite a lot of libs I didn't have (downloaded later from cpan), the entire thing works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

I believe [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/) can do that.

Comment: Indeed it does, and does well. I've been using it for years, and to me it's by far the best price/performance tool for it (among those I used). I've tried StarUML and Together also - the first has potential, but is still incomplete. The second is painfully slow.

Comment: I didn't try Rational Rose, though, since it's well above my acceptable price range.

Answer (score 8):

I find that Wikipedia can be a great source of information about such tools, especially for comparison tables. There's a page on [UML tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UML_tools). See in particular the [reverse engineered languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UML_tools#Features) column.

Answer (score 5):

[UML Studio](http://www.pragsoft.com) does this quite well in my experience, and will run in "freeware mode" for small projects.

Comment: You can run it in free (restricted) mode under Wine.

Answer (score 3):

Seems **Umbrello** produces best UML from C++ code (suggest to use latest version >= 2.22) comparing to command-line **autodia** for **Dia** and other tools.

**StarUML** have not produced good diagrams for me: strange import, not usable, does not work for many people: https://github.com/staruml/Cpp/issues

Answer (score 2):

I have used Rational Rose and Rational Rhapsody for reverse engineering large projects. I would prefer Rational Rhapsody for getting the UML class files for C++ !

Answer (score 1):

Whoever wants UML deserves [Rational Rose](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/swarchitect/standard/) :)

Comment: good program but very expensive !

Comment: The link in this answer is out of date.  The current link is http://www-01.ibm.com/software/rational/products/swarchitect/cpp/

Comment: Both the original link and the one in the comments are out of date. Don't know where to find the current version.

Comment: impossible to find the product page.

Answer (score 1):

[StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/) does just that and it is free. Unfortunately it hasn't been updated for a while. There were a couple of offshoot projects (as the project admins wouldn't allow it to be taken over) but they too have died a death.

Comment: StarUML have not produced good diagrams for me strange import. 

@Rhubbarb, it works under Linux and Mac as well.

Comment: Latest release now is Aug 2018, so it has been picked up again