# Where I can see examples of UML schemes with c++ source

Tags: c++, uml

Where I can see small examples of UML schemes with c++ code. I have no time to read UML standard :(

Comment: Assuming you already know C++ then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405953/generating-uml-from-c-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to read the standard to understand UML. I found this book useful as a quick introduction: [UML Weekend Crash Course](http://www.amazon.co.uk/UML-Weekend-Crash-Course-Pender/dp/0764549103/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1306251319&sr=8-1)

I would also discourage you to think about UML in relation to C++. it's supposed to be a way of modelling systems, not just documenting existing code.

Answer (score 1):

This site has UML diagrams and the corresponding source in C++ and Java --> http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/

Answer (score 1):

The only book you need to read on UML is Fowler's [UML Distilled](http://books.google.com/books/about/UML_distilled.html?id=nHZslSr1gJAC) - it's very short and tells you all you need to know (if you need to know anything, I've never come across UML actually being used in practice). You certainly don't need to plough through the turgid works of the three amigos.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (Structure Diagrams, Behavior Diagrams, Interaction Diagrams)

https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/aads/Online/UML/

Comment: This question has an accepted answer from 2011. It's fairly reasonable to assume that no further answers will be needed.

Comment: well, I am new in Stackoverflow and tried to help.