# Automatically generate a uml diagram of my c++ code

Tags: c++, oop, macos, uml

Some time ago I was a TA in a introductory programming course on Java. We used an IDE called [BlueJ](http://www.bluej.org/) which had the nice feature that the overview of your development files was a light-weight UML diagram with 'usage' pointers and inheritance pointers drawn in, this made it easy to see the structure of the program.

My question is the following, Is there a similar framework for c++? or at least a tool that I can have running next to my editor to keep a clear view of my files and how they are organized.

My development platform is a Mac with emacs as my main editor.

Comment: See similar questions [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405953/generating-uml-from-c-code) and [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407948/c-to-uml-reverse-engineer-round-trip-engineering) and [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577489/c-uml-class-diagram-autogeneration).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know about [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org) and its many options?

In fact, Google's number two hit for Doxygen and UML is [this previous StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755913/how-to-use-doxygen-to-create-uml-class-diagrams-from-c-source).

Comment: Doxygen doesn't create UML class diagrams

Answer (score 0):

To process C++ I recommend BoUML, it will not draw the diagrams automatically, but is quite good in parsing C++ code, and you can create new diagrams, if you add classes to the diagram, the relationships will automatically be displayed, or you can add a single class and then ask for dependencies of that class to be added to the diagram.

Comment: @pseudonym_127: BoUML *used* to be free. I just checked and it seems that the newer versions are not, but you can still download the free versions for different OS from third party webs (softpedia lists it free, for example). History can be read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOUML)