# Tool to draw class hierarchies for c++/Java

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++

I want to draw class hierarchies for some C++ projects.
I have the information in the following format in files.

```
class x: public Y

class Z: public Y

class R: public X .....and so on..
```

I have around 1000 class for the project. Can anyone suggest how should I go about doing it... I mean what tools... what process?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/406130/1715716

Comment: BouML, starUML for open source. But kind of limited.
Otherwise you'll have to pay...

Comment: Arguably you should have started with the diagram (or some form of *design*) before the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use UML diagramming tools. There are a specific category called Unified Modelling Language.
In our school we used `Rational Rose` for that.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/downloads/

And a point to note., 
I haven't done that, But I heard that if you drawn a design with that toos., then could make a skeleton of your code. i.e It could automatically create that much classes and its derivatives, methods, data variables.

Then you need to write the definitions in that auto generated skeleton. So, saving lot of manual works.

http://www-01.ibm.com/software/rational/uml/

Answer (score 3):

Doxygen can do this (and a lot more, like call graphs).

You can get it (and instructions on how to use it) [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/).

Comment: Note you may also need to install GraphViz to render some of Doxygen's diagram types.  Information on the Doxygen site.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) for class diagrams and hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) is greet for generating documentation from code. If you need a tool to make easily a class diagram (online), you can take a look at [GenMyModel](http://www.genmymodel.com).

Answer (score 1):

For reverse engineering/documenting I'd suggest Doxygen, but if you want full UML modelling then [Umbrello](http://uml.sourceforge.net/index.php) may fit the bill (Linux only, though I have sucessfully used it in a VM on Windows).

Answer (score 1):

First, take a look to [uml modeling](http://java-source.net/open-source/uml-modeling). Also, see related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390438/good-free-uml-tool-for-java-eclipse. Another tool is [dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/).