# Write a C code to generate documentation and Diagrams

Tags: c++

i am working on a C++ project with many class. The code was not written by and i have to use and change it new purposes. I am new on working on C++ proyects with many classes.
What software do you guys recommend to generate documentations and a diagram classes interactions?

I want to see the interactions in order to understand the code. My goal right now is to understand the code.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using any particular kde?

Comment: There are different tools you might want to take a look at. For example, douml does reverse engineering from C++. Not perfect, but does a good amount of the work.

Comment: BTW, the title is probably not what you mean, or do you really mean that you want to write C code to generate those diagrams?

Comment: I do not know why  i use that title, really. It suppose to said something like "Generate Documentation and diagramas in a c++ code"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/).

In addition to C++, it supports many 'mainstream languages'.

For generating call graphs and class diagrams, etc., Doxygen requires the [graphviz package](https://graphviz.org/) to be installed.

However, Doxygen cannot render (any or all) 'uses' dependencies among classes, AFAIK.

You may also look into generating UML from C++: [Generating UML from C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/405953/1175253)

Comment: At my shop, Doxygen has been working fine with the C99 language for over 2 years.