# How to generate c++ class diagram with inheritance as well as composition relationship?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, uml

I have been working on a large c++ project, and I want to generate a diagram showing the inheritance as well as composition relationship between classes, I have been googling for a long time seeking for 
a solution. As now, I found a lot of tools (like [understand](https://scitools.com/), or vs) that can be used to generate UML diagram showing **the inheritance relation but not for the composition**.  I really need to see the references between each class for understanding the design pattern inside it, is there any suggestions?

Comment: use rad development tool to generate er diagram to class vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) can generate UML diagrams on a per-class basis including inheritance and composition using the [DOT](http://graphviz.org/) tool. It's only a static tool though.

```
# Modify these settings in your doxygen config file.
UML_LOOK = YES
HAVE_DOT = YES
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue here is not to find a  tool which is able to reverse your c++ code and generating UML class diagrams (take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405953/generating-uml-from-c-code) for example).
You have to find a tool which reverse your code as **compositions** and not simply associations