# how to generate UML class diagram from C++

Tags: c++, uml

I have these 2 structs and 1 class and I want to convert them into UML class:

```
struct cat
{
std::string name;
int id;
};

struct dog
{
std::string name;
std::string owner;
int age;
};

class Pet
{
std::vector<cat> cats;
std::vector<dog> dogs;
//some methods
};
```

i made this:
[image: class diagram]
thank you in advance

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405953/generating-uml-from-c-code) You have an answer on a very similiar question.

Comment: out of the remark of @sweak (where the accepted answer of the similar question starts by a reference to my tool :-) ) if you learn UML I encourage you to first do by hand, so please edit your question with a proposal a class diagram and explain your problem (if you have).

Comment: i want to do it by hand but I can't see what's the link between Pet and the 2 other structs

Comment: @ben in *Pet* *cats* is a multi-valued property of type *cat*, so the type is *cat* and the multiplicity `*` or `0..*` if you prefer, and because of what a `std::vector` is you can also say the property is *ordered*, probably a cat is never duplicated in *cats* so you can also say the property is *unique* (refer to §9.5.4 of http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1). Of course same about dog. Edit your question with a class diagram to check you understand well

Comment: done, so my question is: is it a composition or aggregation between Pet -> cat ?

Comment: @ben `done` : where ? add a link to your diagram in your question (I will make it visible, you do not have enough reputation to make it visible yourself). For your question about composition/aggregation in *Pet* you have vectors of instances, not vectors of pointer, so the instances in *cats* and *dogs* are deleted when the instance of *Pet* is deleted => composition

Comment: i did add a link but is this what are you looking for?

Comment: is it correct what i've made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some remarks :

- *cat* and *dog* are C++ *struct* => their members are *public*, not *private*
- you missed to indicate the types of *name, id, owner* and *age*
- you used associations navigable in the two directions, but a *cat* and a *dog* do not know the corresponding *Pet*
- the association end must be named (*cats / dogs*), and it is useless to also show them through attributes

So, also adding the modifiers I speak about in the comments of your question :

[image]
(I use *cat/dog* rather than *Cat/Dog* to follow the C++ code, but to use *Cat/Dog* is better)

Comment: @ben you welcome. Again, when you put a question include a proposal of solution in it, else people consider you do not made enough research effort and your question can be downvoted and closed without any answer. Good continuation on S.O.